# ReactJS: How to apply classname to two element tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following. But the styling gets only applied to `<th>`. And I tried `#test-table td, #test-table th {}` and `#test-table td th {}`, but nothing get applied then.

css:

```
#test-table td, th {
  color: white;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
}
```

code:

```
    <table className="test-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>head1</th>
          <th>head2</th>
          <th>head3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>col1</td>
          <td>col2</td>
          <td>col2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

How can I apply the styling to both `<td>` and `<th>`? And what is typically the correct hierarchy for css selectors especially for ReactJS? e.g. is the container typically the `className` and any inner elements are defined with `id`?

**EDIT**

How can I achieve:

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dld7.png)

Attempted the following but doesn't work:

```
    <table className="test-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">List</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Monday</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Tuesday</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Names</th>
          <th>Class 1</th><th>Class 2</th>
          <th>Class 1</th><th>Class 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Kev</td>
          <td>abc</td><td>def</td>
          <td>ghi</td><td>jkl</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: create a fiddle or snippet please use `!important`

Comment: In CSS a class selector is a `.`, not a `#` symbol. Also the HTML attribute for classes is `class=""`, not `className=""`. What does ReactJS have to do with the code or problem you've posted?

Comment: @TylerH in react it is `className` because `class` is a reserved word for JS

Comment: @JordanS That may be so but the user has posted what appears to be HTML in his question, where it is `class`.

Comment: But given the title, description, code, and tag, I'm guessing this is react...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `.` because you are referring to a class. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7wbzc4j/1/ which creates the table and applies the CSS.

Comment: thank you! And how about as for the hierarchy of selectors? Should I just always use className for everything?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: when styling with css in ReactJS, do you always just use className? Also before I accept the answer, I forgot to ask, but could you take a look at the original post under Edit? I can't seem to achieve that table.

Comment: You always use className for react components. The reason why your table isn't working is because attributes are camel cased in react. So `colspan` should be `colSpan`. This fiddle is working the way you'd expect: http://jsfiddle.net/k7wbzc4j/2/

Comment: Thank you so much! And By you always use, does it also mean you ONLY use className, and no id and class?

Comment: You can use IDs too, just use className instead of class if you are assigning classes.

Comment: Also I want a `<button/>` to fill a whole cell, and I tried 100% for width and height, but both don't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you send me your current fiddle?

Comment: Never mind got it to work! Thank you. And when should you use ID over className?

Comment: You should use ID for unique elements. This is a bigger topic than I can cover in a comment thread but there are **tons** of excellent resources on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using css selectors, you can use #someId for ids or .someClass for classes, but I'm not aware of a css selector for className.  An option would be to use

```
.test-table td, .test-table th
```

with

```
<table class="test-table">
```

as seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aeuhfpgm/1/)

Comment: `#` selects an ID, they are trying to select their class.

Comment: @craigmasonnc it works for `.test-table td, th {}` as well. Do you know which one is more recommended way of doing it?

Comment: .test-table td, th will select all td's with class test-table and all th's regardless of class. see https://jsfiddle.net/aeuhfpgm/3/